# matching the pattern and concatenting the fileld in two files

Tags: linux, unix

I need a help in matching the pattern and concatenating fields in two files.

eg: I have the following contents in one file:

```
   186.110.12.152 xxx
   186.110.16.123 yyy
```

and the following contents in another file.

```
   186.110.12.152 www.google.com 
   186.110.16.123 www.facebook.com
```

now I need to get the user name at the beginning of the output. 
if I search for the xxx, I have to get the output as

```
  xxx 186.110.12.152 www.google.com
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` command

```
join firstfile secondfile > output.txt
```

For more information check this [article](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ujoin.htm).

And to be exact according to **output FORMAT** in question you need to follow this formatting using `-o` option,

```
join -o 1.2 2.1 2.2 firstfile secondfile |tee output.txt
```

the **output** will be;

```
xxx 186.110.12.152 www.google.com 
yyy 186.110.16.123 www.facebook.com
```

Here is what I tried,

[image]

The **explanation** of above command is as follows,

`-o` It used to format the output of join command.

`1.2` It signify firstfile's second column.

`2.1` It signify secondfile's first column.

`2.2` It signify secondfile's second column.

`tee` command will redirect the output of `join` command to a file as well as standard output (i.e:console).

`output.txt` will record the output of the join command.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the `join` command. This is for joining files based on the contents of a column.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/join